# Renaming domain (2008 R2) with SharePoint 2010

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2010, rename

Does anyone have clear steps how to approach SharePoint 2010 when renaming domain. We need to rename single labeled domain before introducing Exchange 2010 and many other stuff in our network.

What problems do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SharePoint installed in a SLD environment? If that is the case, it is unsupported, I suggest that you uninstall SP, rename the domain, and then re-install SP.

Comment: Actually I've tested rename Single Domain Name CompanyPL to Company.PL (fqdn) and left netbios the same companypl... and sharepoint even didn't needed any action on my side.. I will do few more tests to be sure but basically it seems that rename on SharePoint works with no problems as long netbios is not touched.